# The this-variable is the Window object or undefined in the then-method of a promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

In ES2015 (formerly ES6), I thought using the arrow syntax should lead the `this` variable to be the object you are in, making the old `var that = this` technique obsolete.

However, in my function for the `then`-part of a Promise, the `this` variable is the `Window` object (in Chrome) or `undefined` (in FF and IE11):

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class InvoiceGenerator {
    items = [];

    constructor(http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    activate() {
        this.http
            .get(`http://${window.location.host}/api/invoice`)
            .then(response => {
                this.something = response.someProperty; // this is the Window 
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err); 
            });
    }
}
```

I'm using Aurelia by the way, in case it is important.

How can I get the `this` variable to be the object I am currently in (my Aurelia viewmodel), without using the old `var that = this` technique?

Comment: That seems fine to me, `this` would be whatever the `this` is that you are reading `this.http` from. You'd have to show more code the repro the problem, otherwise I'm not sure what anyone can say.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the full code now. So it is executed in the context of my viewmodel object, not the Window object.

Comment: Can you post the ES5 code this generates?

Comment: It should be this, as I'm using Babel: http://tiny.cc/3slazx

Comment: I also just noticed that the variable is undefined in IE11 and Firefox...

Comment: In your code, `this` would be the instance of `InvoiceGenerator`. Is that not what your seeing? The Babel link you posted certainly looks like code that would work in IE11 and FF.

Comment: Indeed, you would think so. But it's not what I'm seeing. However, it should work, because the Aurelia skeleton-navigation app works the same way. So it must be something I'm doing... I'll try reproduce it in a Plunker.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare 'something' property in your class before referring it with 'this' in the callback because the 'this' in callback does not contain 'something' property nor will it create it.

```
export class InvoiceGenerator {
    something = [];

    constructor(http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    activate() {
        this.http
            .get(`http://${window.location.host}/api/invoice`)
            .then(response => {
                this.something = response.someProperty; // this is the Window 
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err); 
        });
    }
}
```

I have not tried it but I believe Typescript would have caught the error.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that "the arrow syntax should lead the `this` variable to be the object you are in," but you're confused about what object you're "in." When you do this:

```
this.http
  .get(`http://${window.location.host}/api/invoice`)
  .then(response => {
    this.something = response.someProperty; // this is the Window object
  });
```

It's equivalent to this:

```
let thenFn = response => { this.something = response.someProperty; }

this.http
  .get(`http://${window.location.host}/api/invoice`)
  .then(thenFn);
```

Defining the function inside the parentheses (`then(response => ...)`) doesn't change the fact that you're defining it in the same context in which `this.http` exists—which in your case is apparently `window`.

Unfortunately I can't tell you how to make `this` refer to your Aurelia viewmodel because you haven't shown your viewmodel code or any other context.